# Change text color of inner class placeholder

Tags: css, placeholder, pseudo-element

I'm struggling with a fairly trivial problem I assume, never having had prior experience with CSS. How do I change the placeholder text color of something like this?

```
<div class="square">
  <input class="circle" placeholder="blue" />
</div>
```

I thought something like this might work, but it didn't

```
.square{
      .circle::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: blue;
      }
}
```

Also, I would like to know how to accomplish the same if its nested further down the hierarchy. Would it be possible to skip elements in between the target placeholder and the outer element?

Comment: You can't do that with pure CSS, but you can do it with SCSS or so.

Answer (score 1):

To target the .circle element inside a .square element, you want to write :

```
.square .circle::-webkit-input-placeholder {
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your syntax to the code below:

```css
.square .circle::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
  <input class="circle" placeholder="blue" />
</div>
```

*It seems like you've used a SASS syntax.*

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this..and check [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/)

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```